# Unable to change ARGB to YUV420Planar

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, mediamuxer

I'm attempting to use MediaCodec and MediaMuxer to change a series of JPEGs into a mp4.

No matter what I do, I always get a green staticy screen as output on the MP4.

Code Follows:

```
 public class AvcEncoder
{
    public bool CanEncode = true;

    MediaCodec codec;
    MediaMuxer muxer;
    MediaFormat format;
    public AvcEncoder()
    {
        codec = MediaCodec.CreateEncoderByType("video/avc");
        format = MediaFormat.CreateVideoFormat("video/avc", 720, 480);
        format.SetInteger(MediaFormat.KeyBitRate, 700000);
        format.SetInteger(MediaFormat.KeyFrameRate, 10);
        format.SetInteger(MediaFormat.KeyColorFormat, (int)Android.Media.MediaCodecCapabilities.Formatyuv420planar);
        format.SetInteger(MediaFormat.KeyIFrameInterval, 5);
        codec.Configure(format, null, null, MediaCodecConfigFlags.Encode);
        codec.Start();
        Java.IO.File f = new Java.IO.File(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory, "Parkingdom");
        if (!f.Exists())
        {
            f.Mkdirs();
        }
        muxer = new MediaMuxer(f.ToString() + "/test.mp4", MuxerOutputType.Mpeg4);
    }

    public void EncodeFrame(Bitmap image)
    {
        int mWidth = image.Width;
        int mHeight = image.Height;

        int[] mIntArray = new int[mWidth * mHeight];

        // Copy pixel data from the Bitmap into the 'intArray' array
        image.GetPixels(mIntArray, 0, mWidth, 0, 0, mWidth, mHeight);
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[mWidth * mHeight * 3 / 2];
        // Call to encoding function : convert intArray to Yuv Binary data
        EncodeYUV420P(byteArray, mIntArray, mWidth, mHeight);


        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, stream);
            byteArray = stream.ToArray();
        }

        int inputBufferIndex = codec.DequeueInputBuffer(-1);
        if (inputBufferIndex >= 0)
        {
            ByteBuffer buffer = codec.GetInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex);
            buffer.Clear();
            buffer.Put(byteArray);
            codec.QueueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, byteArray.Length, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    public void SaveMp4()
    {

        CanEncode = false;
        bool running = true;
        MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
        int track = -1;

        while (running)
        {
            int index = codec.DequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 10000);
            if (index == (int)MediaCodecInfoState.OutputFormatChanged)
            {
                MediaFormat format = codec.OutputFormat;
                track = muxer.AddTrack(format);
                muxer.Start();
            }
            else if (index == (int)MediaCodecInfoState.TryAgainLater)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if (index >= 0)
            {
                if ((bufferInfo.Flags & MediaCodecBufferFlags.CodecConfig) != 0)
                {
                    bufferInfo.Size = 0;
                }


                if (track != -1)
                {
                    ByteBuffer outBuffer = codec.GetOutputBuffer(index);
                    outBuffer.Position(bufferInfo.Offset);
                    outBuffer.Limit(bufferInfo.Offset + bufferInfo.Size);
                    muxer.WriteSampleData(track, outBuffer, bufferInfo);
                    codec.ReleaseOutputBuffer(index, false);
                }
            }
        }

        codec.Stop();
        codec.Release();
        muxer.Stop();
        muxer.Release();

        CanEncode = true;

    }

    void EncodeYUV420P(byte[] yuv420p, int[] argb, int width, int height)
    {
        int frameSize = width * height;
        int chromasize = frameSize / 4;


        int yIndex = 0;
        int uIndex = frameSize;
        int vIndex = frameSize + chromasize;

        int a, R, G, B, Y, U, V;
        int index = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
            {

                a = (int)(argb[index] & 0xff000000) >> 24; // a is not used obviously
                R = (argb[index] & 0xff0000) >> 16;
                G = (argb[index] & 0xff00) >> 8;
                B = (argb[index] & 0xff) >> 0;

                Y = ((66 * R + 129 * G + 25 * B + 128) >> 8) + 16;
                U = ((-38 * R - 74 * G + 112 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128;
                V = ((112 * R - 94 * G - 18 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128;


                yuv420p[yIndex++] = (byte)((Y < 0) ? 0 : ((Y > 255) ? 255 : Y));
                if (j % 2 == 0 && index % 2 == 0)
                {
                    yuv420p[uIndex++] = (byte)((U < 0) ? 0 : ((U > 255) ? 255 : U));
                    yuv420p[vIndex++] = (byte)((V < 0) ? 0 : ((V > 255) ? 255 : V));
                }

                index++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Each time a new jpeg is generated "EncodeFrame" is called which is supposed to be changing it into a YUV420Planar format for the media codec. The codec I'm testing with doesn't support semiplanar.

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm using Xamarin, thats why the code is in C#

Comment: I just realized I was overwriting my byteArray with old code

            `using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                image.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, stream);
            / byteArray = stream.ToArray();
            }`

However the code still isn't working after removing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone comes across this later I changed

EncodeFrame to use a Surface instead and just used DrawBitmap().

It's slower than the byte copy but is working for my purposes.